# How to calculate the start time and destroy time of 'php sessions'?

Tags: php, session, authentication, logout

I want to calculate the time duration of php sessions.The time will start when the session will be created and it will end when session will be destroyed.

Actually I am using this technique to calculate the login and logout time of user.When user will be logged in, a session will be created and time will be noted and the same for logout

Comment: Can't you just store the start time in the session?  You haven't given much to go on.

Comment: do you have some code? and clear your question

Comment: What about those people that dont bother to logout

Comment: @Devon i'll consider that

Comment: @RiggsFolly when user closes the browser window,they will be logout anyway

Comment: Really, you have something that will do that do you, cause it sure aint automatic

Answer (score 0):

You can use sessions and database to calculate the time duration of a php session.
When the session is created for the first time(when user logging in) store current date and time in a session(or database) and when the login session is going to be destroyed (when user logging out) Calculate duration like this:

duration=logout_datetime - login_datetime

```
//Example Login Code:
if ($username=="ok" && $password =="ok") {
    ....//Create login sessions and send cookies
    if (!isset($_SESSION['time'])) {//Save login datetime to the session
        $_SESSION['time']=time();
    }
}

//Example Logout Code:
$duration=time() - $_SESSION['time']; //calculate duration
echo "Time user was logged in is".$duration;
session_destroy();
```

you are free to use database or sessions to store login time.
Sorry for possible language mistakes as English is not my native language

Answer (score 0):

Please look into session_set_save_handler. It allows you to call custom functions whenever a session is created or destroyed. Following code has been copied from http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php

```
<?php
class FileSessionHandler
{
    private $savePath;

    function open($savePath, $sessionName)
    {
        $this->savePath = $savePath;
        if (!is_dir($this->savePath)) {
            mkdir($this->savePath, 0777);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function close()
    {
        return true;
    }

    function read($id)
    {
        return (string)@file_get_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id");
    }

    function write($id, $data)
    {
        return file_put_contents("$this->savePath/sess_$id", $data) === false ? false : true;
    }

    function destroy($id)
    {
        $file = "$this->savePath/sess_$id";
        if (file_exists($file)) {
            unlink($file);
        }

        return true;
    }

    function gc($maxlifetime)
    {
        foreach (glob("$this->savePath/sess_*") as $file) {
            if (filemtime($file) + $maxlifetime < time() && file_exists($file)) {
                unlink($file);
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
}

$handler = new FileSessionHandler();
session_set_save_handler(
    array($handler, 'open'),
    array($handler, 'close'),
    array($handler, 'read'),
    array($handler, 'write'),
    array($handler, 'destroy'),
    array($handler, 'gc')
);

// the following prevents unexpected effects when using objects as save handlers
register_shutdown_function('session_write_close');

session_start();
// proceed to set and retrieve values by key from $_SESSION
```